# Spring SecurityContextHolder doesn't mantain authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to manually authenticate to Spring Security through REST API. I've managed to open an endpoint where users can perfom the authentication. The endpoint works only whithin itself. If I try to get data from other secured endpoints the authentication is not provided. It seems that the user is authenticated but not remembered. Am I missing some steps?

Here's my endpoint where users can login:

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/account/login")
public class LoginRestController {

    @Autowired
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @PostMapping("")
    public ResponseEntity<String> login(@RequestBody LoginPayload payload) {
        try {
            Authentication auth = authenticationManager
                    .authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(payload.getEmail(), payload.getPassword()));

            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            return new ResponseEntity<>("Utente autenticato", HttpStatus.OK);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
            return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
    }
}
```

here's my configuration:

```java
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                        .requestMatchers("/api/account/register", "/api/account/register/**").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/account/login").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api/aziende/exists").permitAll()
                        .requestMatchers("/api", "/api/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/app", "/app/**").authenticated()
                        .requestMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()

                )
                .formLogin((form) -> form.loginPage("/accedi").permitAll())
                .logout((logout) -> logout.logoutUrl("/esci").permitAll());

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }
}
```

Comment: My client is postman, it seems that jsessionid is set

Comment: At a high level you need spring security to intercept all the requests and validate them for authorization, in your above example it only does for "" url. You need to customize some spring filters in your SecurityFilterChain based on your auth needs e.g. form based auth or basic etc etc and provide a way to lookup the user that is being authenticated... e.g. https://howtodoinjava.com/spring5/security/login-form-example/

Comment: Yes, you are missing. If you are on Spring Security 6 you have to explicit save the `SecurityContext` https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/5.8/migration/servlet/session-management.html#_require_explicit_saving_of_securitycontextrepository

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio If you post that as an answer, you have my upvote.

Comment: @MarcusHertdaCoregio I've updated my answer according to the documentation you've provided me. is it correct in this way?

Answer (score -4):

UPDATED:

As @MarcusHertdaCoregio said I had to save the context with the securitycontextrepository. Here's the code:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http = http.csrf().disable();

        http = http.authorizeHttpRequests((requests) -> requests
                .requestMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api/aziende/exists").permitAll()
                .requestMatchers("/api", "/api/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/app", "/app/**").authenticated()
                .requestMatchers("/admin", "/admin/**").hasAnyAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")
                .requestMatchers("/", "/**").permitAll()

        );

        http = http.formLogin((form) -> form.loginPage("/accedi").permitAll());

        http = http.logout((logout) -> logout.logoutUrl("/esci").logoutSuccessUrl("/").permitAll());

        http = http.securityContext((securityContext) -> securityContext
                .requireExplicitSave(true));

        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(
            AuthenticationConfiguration configuration) throws Exception {
        return configuration.getAuthenticationManager();
    }

    @Bean
    SecurityContextRepository securityContextRepository() {
        return new HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository();
    }
}
```

```java
    @PostMapping("/login")
    public ResponseEntity<?> login(@RequestBody Login payload, HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) {
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.createEmptyContext();

        try {
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(payload.getEmail(),
                    payload.getPassword());

            Authentication auth = authManager.authenticate(token);

            if (auth.isAuthenticated()) {
                context.setAuthentication(auth);
                SecurityContextHolder.setContext(context);

                securityContextRepository.saveContext(context, request, response);

                return ResponseEntity.ok("utente autenticato");
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.status(401).body("credenziali non valide");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(401).body(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be creating and managing sessions like this yourself. Instead you should be using the built-in Spring Security persistence mechanisms (which _may_ use sessions if configured so): https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/authentication/persistence.html